# Read Internet header in each outlook 2003 mail

Tags: c#, outlook-2003

I am developed an application which works in all version of outlook (2003,2007, 2010). In that project i process internet header information of each outlook mail. I am done with outlook versions (2007, 2010) using PropertyAccessor property.  I found the PropertyAccessor is available only for outlook versions (2007, 2010).  i want to process internet header information of each oulook 2003 mail also. i done using redemtion dll (third party) to overcome the above problem. can anybody assist me is there any other option to overcome the issue or suggest me is redemtion dll approach is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Working for the past 3 years on a big Outlook (2003,2007,2010,2013) project I can concur that using Redemption is the right approach, that's what I did for Outlook 2003 and it works very well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i am proceeding with the Redemption approach only.  i need to know how can i install "redemption dll" as part of my installation setup in Visual Studio. While installing separately  "redemption dll" thought their installation it work fine but it not works with my Visual studion installation package. Any suggestion

Comment: I simply use regsvr32 on the dll (with the correct bitness) or you can use RedemptionLoader that doesn't require registering the dll (see: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm)